Rust oracle mtls connection
How to connect to Oracle database which is enabled with mTLS?
I tried using rust oracle crate but wasn't successful. Please suggest/help on this. The idea is to connect to oracle DB and extract some data but since it is mtls enabled, I'm not able to establish connection.

Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow! To make sure you get good answers to your question, please take some time to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question accordingly. Specifically, you're not saying what exactly you already tried and why it did not work. Usually a minimal example should be included that others could use to reproduce the problem.

I assume this is a question about connecting to Oracle Autonomous Database using rust-oracle.
Follow the general techniques for other Oracle 'thick' mode drivers that utilize Oracle Client libraries, for example see the 'Thick mode' sections of the python-oracledb documentation.

Make sure to download the correct mTLS wallet from the Oracle ADB cloud console

Unzip the wallet file. You just need three files:

tnsnames.ora - Maps net service names used for application connection strings to your database services
sqlnet.ora - Configures Oracle Network settings
cwallet.sso - Enables SSL/TLS connections in Thick mode. Keep this file secure



You then have two options:

Either move the extracted files to a default location, such as in the Instant Client network/admin subdirectory.
Or the second option is to move the extracted files to a central location. Then edit the file sqlnet.ora to set the wallet location DIRECTORY path to the directory where the files are.  Then set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to that same directory name.

With either option, you would then just run your app using one of the connection aliases in the tnsnames.ora file (along with your database username and password):
let conn = Connection::connect("scott", "tiger", "mydb_high")?;

